# How to make a different target_include_directories for internal and external #includes for a header-only library in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, interface, header-only

The directory structure for my header-only library is as follows:

```
proj/
    include/
        proj/
            file1.h
            file2.h
    CMakeLists.txt
```

Basically I would like to be able to do the following inside file1.h (and therefore anywhere within the project):

```
#include "file2.h"
```

But have to do the following in any external project:

```
#include "proj/file2.h"
```

Currently, my naive implementation of this is in CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library( proj INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( proj INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
target_include_directories( proj INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/proj )
```

To allow both internal and external files do be able to do both. This is not restrictive enough, however, and what I am looking for is something that would work equivalently to this:

```
add_library( proj INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( proj INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
target_include_directories( proj PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/proj )
```

But this obviously results in a CMake error because:

```
target_include_directories may only set INTERFACE properties on INTERFACE targets
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: CMake doesn't differentiate users of the library: all INTERFACE properties of the library are propagated to anyone which links with that library. When access library's *interface* headers, it is better to use **same include paths** both inside the project and outside of it. This preference is applicable even for normal (not-header-only) libraries, when you actually can differentiate users by setting PRIVATE and INTERFACE properties.

Comment: The #include statements are not resolved until the c++ file(s) using this library are compiled, so this is when the configured paths must be known. This means that all the include paths of an INTERFACE library must be non-private for the compilation to work.

Comment: Thank you for you answers, they both make sense to me.

@Tsyvarev, what is the reasoning behind this preference even for not-header-only libraries?

Comment: The reasoning behind a single way for using some interface (the header file in your case) is a simpler support and a lesser chance of making errors.